# Remove custom tag from a string then format its content

Tags: java, android, regex

I need help to parse, modify and show a string on an Android App (Java language, max API level 22)

This is a example string I'm getting from an API which contains only custom tag:

```
<BOLD> Something <RED> went wrong </RED> </BOLD> <NEWLINE> Server unreachable </NEWLINE>
```

I need to remove all this custom tags then format its content based on the tags that were wrapping that substring (so I'm expeting, for example, to get "went wrong" in red color and bold). I already tried looking up for similar problems but can't get to the final result.

The string (cleaned and formatted) will then be used to set the Text of a TextView inside a List View

Comment: I think you mean MIN API Level 22, not max.
You'll need to look into spans. I recommend this series of posts about them. https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/spantastic-text-styling-with-spans-17b0c16b4568

Comment: It's an old app I'm updating that needs to run on old devices, it's indeed locked to level 22 and below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing this is like this....

```
       String testString="<BOLD> Something <RED> went wrong </RED> </BOLD> <NEWLINE> Server unreachable </NEWLINE>"; 

       testString=testString.replaceAll("<BOLD>","<font> <b>");

        testString=testString.replaceAll("</BOLD>","</b> </font>");

        testString=testString.replaceAll("<RED>","<font color =\"#FF0000\">");  //#FF0000 is hex code for red color

        testString=testString.replaceAll("</RED>","</font> ");

        testString=testString.replaceAll("<NEWLINE>","<br>");

        testString=testString.replaceAll("</NEWLINE>","");

        TextView textView=findViewById(R.id.text);
        textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(testString));
```

Output :

[image]

Comment: This is working for my case. If I wanted to add an icon using img HTML tag what would be the path if I have my png in the drawable folder? This is the last problem I'm facing. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @Steven ... You have to use spannable for that I guess I haven't tried it before...so sorry

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into that. Side note: to format my NEWLINE custom tag che correct way is using `<br />` instead of `\n`

Answer (score 0):

**Using Regex (Regular Expressions)**

Just give your string to the Regex Pattern and it removes all the extra tags for you.

---

**Kotlin**

This removes all the HTML tags inside your String:

```
val result = yourString.replace(Regex("(<[a-z]*>)|(<.[a-z]*>)"), "")
```

---

**Java**

```
String result = yourString.replaceAll("(<[a-z]*>)|(<.[a-z]*>)", "");
```